# DNS cname resolving always results in error

Tags: node.js, dns

```
$ node
> const dns = require('dns');
> dns.resolveMx('nodejs.org', (err, value) => { 
    if(err) { 
        console.log(err); 
        return; 
    } 
    console.log(value); 
})
> [
  { exchange: 'aspmx2.googlemail.com', priority: 30 },
  { exchange: 'aspmx3.googlemail.com', priority: 30 },
  { exchange: 'aspmx.l.google.com', priority: 10 },
  { exchange: 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com', priority: 20 },
  { exchange: 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com', priority: 20 }
]
> dns.resolveCname('nodejs.org', (err, value) => { 
    if(err) { 
        console.log(err); 
        return; 
    } 
    console.log(value); 
})
> Error: queryCname ENODATA nodejs.org
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ENODATA',
  syscall: 'queryCname',
  hostname: 'nodejs.org'
}
```

why?

In other words, resolving CNAME for a given host is throwing `ENODATA` error, always. I tested this in my machine & in an EC2 instance. I get the same results. I checked & opened DNS ports in EC2 instance. I still got the error.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Because those domains don't have a CNAME set?

Comment: May be, `nodejs.org` does not. I also checked using a domain where I have added the CNAME record. I got the same response.

Comment: `DNS` NODATA is not exactly an error, and it is a pseudo one anyway. It just means that the name you query for exists (otherwise you would get NXDOMAIN error) but the record type you want for this name does not exist. Hence "no data".  And per DNS rules, you can't have a `CNAME` at apex.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the `dns.resolveCname` API was incorrect.
It appears that, the resolving happens at the given host level.

If I use `nodejs.org` for Cname resolution, it always gives `ENODATA` error. But, if I use `docs.nodejs.org` for Cname resolution, it gives `[ 'nodejs.org' ]`.

So, if the given hostname does not have any CNAME associated to it, `dns.resolveCname` always gives `ENODATA`.

Comment: "If I use nodejs.org for Cname resolution, it always gives ENODATA error." You can not have a CNAME record at apex, for any zone. This is per standard DNS design.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, you want to write your comments as Answer? I will accept that.